# Are there any best books to learn tenses in English?

Tags: discussion

I want to find some good reference books in English. Especially, the books which explain tenses.

Comment: This is probably not the right forum to ask this question; you're better off posting that on https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @OliverMason I think that this question is off-topic too in ELL. Questions about recommending books are "primarily opinion-based" which is off-topic in many Exchange sites.

Comment: Check out over on [Language Learners.SE](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com).also.

Comment: Vavilala, there are only two tenses in English: past and present, just like in many other languages, so it's really very simple and you don't need a book on that, it's self-explanatory. What English has on top of that is aspects (like progressive or perfect), and these are the tricky part. For those you can turn to CGEL, but that is a very advanced book that I can only recommend reading once you're already fluent in English. Until then I'd really not bother with grammar books, especially not those that say that there are more than two tenses. You will never learn English from those.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: [Huddleston and Pullum classify the perfect as a tense](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Huddleston_and_Pullum%27s_(2002)_analysis_of_tense) (according to their analysis, the contrast between perfect and non-perfect tenses constitutes a "secondary tense" system, whereas the contrast between past and present/non-past tenses is the "primary tense" system). The "only two tenses" view is far from the only position taken by serious linguists.

Comment: Book recommendations should not be open-ended, since they are then opinion-based. You can try formulating very specific criteria using Jeff Atwood's advice in [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and re-ask your question, e.g. on English Language Learning SE or on [Language Learning Stack Exchange](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/). (Jeff Atwood is one of the co-founders of Stack Exchange.)

Comment: This question is off topic. But "serious linguists" and "beginning learners of English" are worlds apart.